# Convert DateTime format to Matlab Date Serial Number format

Tags: c#, winforms, matlab, datetime, format

I want to be able to convert the DateTime (2012/12/31 10-21-17.617) to a decimal number that Matlab takes (Date Serial Number).

I have converted the Matlab date serial number to the Datetime format (`yyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss.fff`) by using this:

```
DateTime conv = new DateTime(1, 1, 1).AddDays(734139.045000000040).AddYears(-1)
```

However i would like to be able to do the opposite of the above. I know the .NET date starts from `0001/01/01` where as for Matlab it is `0000/00/00`.

Comment: I don't feel I understand your question completely but you might need to use `.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-1)` as well if you want to get it from `0000/00/00`

Comment: @Soner - Thank you for that, simply put i want to be able to convert the datetime format in the first line of my question to a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, a simple approach would be TimeSpan.TotalDays (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx)

Create a timespan from an arbitrary point to the DateTime you're trying to convert, then adjust as necessary with the offset to get it into matlab format.
Added code example

```
    private DateTime MatlabToNET(double days)
    {
        return new DateTime(1, 1, 1).AddDays(days).AddYears(-1);
    }

    private double NETtoMatlab(DateTime dt)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = dt - new DateTime();
        return ts.TotalDays + 365;
    }
```